Can I secure a single set of APIs with two different Azure AD B2C tenants?
Can I secure a web api from two different Azure AD B2C tenants so two different mobile apps can use the same apis?
I would test but the configuration has been so finicky and the new interface, which I will get use to and does look better, is an additional complexity. I don't want to mess with what I have in place and impact end users if this is not possible.
It would be much easier if I could use Bicep, but I don't know if that is on the roadmap or even possible given the ad component.
What settings do I use in the appsetting.json to support a second identity provider.
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://[identity url]",
    "ClientId": "[client id]",
    "CallbackPath": "/[callback path]",
    "Domain": "[domain]",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "[susi flow]",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "[reset flow]",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "[edit flow]"
  },

and in the startup.cs:
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options => 
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
            },
            options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });

Do I add a second set of settings and add a 2nd provider?
UPDATE
I tried with two settings in the appsetting.json like:
  "AzureAdB2C": {
        "Instance": "https://[identity url]",
        "ClientId": "[client id]",
        "CallbackPath": "/[callback path]",
        "Domain": "[domain]",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "[susi flow]",
        "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "[reset flow]",
        "EditProfilePolicyId": "[edit flow]"
  },
  "AzureAdB2C2": {
        "Instance": "https://[identity url2]",
        "ClientId": "[client id2]",
        "CallbackPath": "/[callback path2]",
        "Domain": "[domain2]",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "[susi flow2]",
        "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "[reset flow2]",
        "EditProfilePolicyId": "[edit flow2]"

I tried with:
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options => 
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
            },
            options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options => 
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C2", options);
            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        },
        options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C2", options); });

But got this:
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
      System.InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Bearer



I'm not sure what you mean by "secure," but if the two tenants are using custom policies and the policy calls an API, then yes, they can both call the same API.
Update
Mobile app. 1 has an appsetting.json to authenticate to tenant 1.
Mobile app. 2 has an appsetting.json to authenticate to tenant 2.
In the custom policy for app1 on tenant1, call the API via the REST API technical policy.
In the custom policy for app2 on tenant2, call the API via the REST API technical policy.
REST API TP details.

Ok. I'm going to test it out now. Thank you. By "secure" I mean require authentication.

I tried but got an error message and updated the original post.

Please provide a diagram of what you are trying to achieve. The way I read the questions, you have two tenants, each with an application, but want to use a third-party API. In this case, just call the API from the custom policy. There is no need for two app settings.

I updated the question with a diagram.

The appsettings.json is for the API...the mobile app configuration is different.
